# How to make a boolean variable switch between true and false every time a method is invoked?

Tags: java, boolean

I am trying to write a method that when invoked, changes a boolean variable to true, and when invoked again, changes the same variable to false, etc.

For example:
call method -> boolean = true -> call method -> boolean = false -> call method -> boolean = true

So basically,

```
if (a = false) { a = true; }
if (a = true) { a = false; }
```

I am not sure how to accomplish this, because every time I call the method, the boolean value changes to true and then false again.

Comment: if that was actual code you tried, keep in mind that `a = false` is **setting** a to false, not testing it. use `a == false` or better yet `!a` to test if a boolean is false.

Comment: wont that just set a = true, which then triggers the 2nd if and set a = false again. you need if else on your 2nd line

Answer (score 128):

```
value ^= true;
```

That is value xor-equals true, which will flip it every time, and without any branching or temporary variables.

Comment: There are usually more readable ways to do this, such as Randy's answer.

Comment: I agree it is less readable. However, I don't think it is sloppy, nor is it incorrect, the two criteria suggested for a down vote.

Comment: Well, it depends.  If the class' function or a significant part of it's internal state is fundamentally togglable, then yes: a toggleFoo() function is indicated, and it is probably more readable.  However, if the boolean is a local variable, foo^=true is perfectly readable and doesn't clutter the class with irrelevant methods.

Comment: never seen this kind of flip before,upvote for inspiration!

Comment: I like it.  While the traditional a=!a works pretty well (and, correct me if I'm wrong, is slightly more efficient), this is a nice alternative for variables with long names.  A good way to improve readability.

Answer (score 55):

Without looking at it, set it to not itself. I don't know how to code it in Java, but in Objective-C I would say

```
booleanVariable = !booleanVariable;
```

This flips the variable.

Comment: It's the same in Java.

Answer (score 43):

Just toggle each time it is called

```
this.boolValue = !this.boolValue;
```

Answer (score 18):

Assuming your code above is the actual code, you have two problems:

1) your if statements need to be '==', not '='. You want to do comparison, not assignment.

2) The second if should be an 'else if'. Otherwise when it's false, you will set it to true, then the second if will be evaluated, and you'll set it back to false, as you describe

```
if (a == false) {
  a = true;
} else if (a == true) {
  a = false;
}
```

Another thing that would make it even simpler is the '!' operator:

```
a = !a;
```

will switch the value of a.

Comment: The second if, if (a==true) isn't even necessary, just else suffices, unless it's a Boolean which might have a null value.

Comment: True, but I always prefer to err on the side of being explicit in my intent, especially when answering questions such as these.

Comment: While the first solution is not thread-safe (2 checks), the second one is.

Answer (score 16):

I do it with `boolean = !boolean;`

Answer (score 9):

```
value = (value) ? false : true;
```

[Conditional (ternary) Operator.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 7):

```
var logged_in = false;
logged_in = !logged_in;
```

A little example:

```js
var logged_in = false;


$("#enable").click(function() {
    logged_in = !logged_in;
    checkLogin();
});

function checkLogin(){
    if (logged_in)
        $("#id_test").removeClass("test").addClass("test_hidde");
    else
        $("#id_test").removeClass("test_hidde").addClass("test");
    $("#id_test").text($("#id_test").text()+', '+logged_in);
}
```

```css
.test{
    color: red;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 100000px
}

.test_hidde{
    color: #000;
    font-size: 26px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test" id="id_test">Some Content...</div>
<div style="display: none" id="id_test">Some Other Content...</div>


<div>
    <button id="enable">Edit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
private boolean negate(boolean val) {
    return !val;
}
```

I think that is what you are asking for??

Answer (score 2):

in java when you set a value to variable, it return new value. So

```
private boolean getValue()
{
     return value = !value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

here are some ways to do it, pick the one you like:

```
//set a bool variable to true
bool myBool = true;
print (myBool); //:true

//set 'myBool' to not itself
myBool = !myBool;
print (myBool); //:false

//ternary myBool: if it's true return false, if it's false return true
myBool = myBool ? false : true;
print (myBool); //:true

//ternary !myBool, same as last one but inverted (because why not)
myBool = !myBool ? true : false;
print (myBool); //:false

//set myBool to not itself and true
myBool = !(myBool && true)
print (myBool); //:true
```

Jokes aside, I always wanted a function to call like `myBool.switch()` to set it to not itself and return the new value, can't find any downsides to this one. :)

Comment: Neither java code, nor does it add any value. Suggestions: 1) Not the question 2) Already stated in different answeres 3) Bad style (use !myBool) 4) Same, but even worse 5) myBool is already a boolean. Why use this and-operation?

Comment: Can you like change one character so that I can remove the downvote? (I'll delete this comment)