# How to use 2+ ToggleButtons to Get the Buttons' Total Value?

Tags: java, android, togglebutton

I'm trying to make an app (my first) that shows the value of binary numbers in a decimal display. I decided to use a `ToggleButton` with an image of a 1 or a 0 showing whether it is pressed or not. I managed to link '1' up to a `TextView` so that when when the `ToggleButton` is pressed it shows "Binary equals: 1" below it and likewise for 0.

I thought adding a second button would be easy but after 5 (10?) hours of Googling and experimenting I have no idea how to do that.

I have tried [case breaks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gh4nX-m6BEo) but as I have only been programming for two weeks ([udacity Android Development for Beginners](https://www.udacity.com/course/android-development-for-beginners--ud837) so far) I have no idea where to go next or if I'm on the right track—were `ToggleButtons` a bad idea, for example?

I think what I need to do is this:

1) If `toggle1` is selected, make `valueOfOnes` = 1, else `valueOfOnes` = 0

2) If `toggle2` (and eventually 4, 8, 16...) is selected make `valueOfTwos` = 2 else = 0

3) Make a method that adds `valueOfOnes` to `valueOfTwos` etc

4) Show that value in `Textview`

Hope the code below doesn't look too messy. It's tidier than my brain was earlier on...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="16dp"
tools:context="com.example.android.binary02.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3">

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggle2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/check"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn="" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggle1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/check"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn="" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Binary equals: "
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/decimal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="50sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

CHECK XML

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- When selected, show one -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/one"
    android:state_checked="true" />
<!-- When not selected, show two-->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zero"
    android:state_checked="false"/>

</selector>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.android.binary02;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
                          implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    ToggleButton toggle1;
    ToggleButton toggle2;
    TextView decimalAnswer;
    int valueOfOnes = 1;
    int valueOfTwos = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toggle1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggle1);
        toggle1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        toggle2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggle2);
        toggle2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        decimalAnswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.decimal);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged (CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean oneSelected) {
        if(oneSelected) {
            int valueOfOnes = 1;
            addValues(valueOfOnes);
        }
        else
        {
            int valueOfOnes = 0;
            addValues(valueOfOnes);

        }
    }

    /** If this method is commented out and relevant changes made to addValues then one button works fine
     *
     * @param compoundButton
     * @param oneSelected
     */
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChangedTwo (CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean twoSelected) {
        if(twoSelected) {
            int valueOfTwos = 2;
            addValues(valueOfTwos);
        }
        else
        {
            int valueOfTwos = 0;
            addValues(valueOfTwos);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Adds values together.
     *
     * If I delete the int valueOfTwos here and replace with +1 or +0 then the app works (but only for one button it looks like both buttons perform the same action)
     *
     */
    public void addValues(int valueOfOnes, int valueOfTwos) {
        int totalValues;
        totalValues = valueOfOnes + valueOfTwos;
        displayDecimalAnswer(totalValues);
    }

    /**
     * Displays decimal answer.
     */
    public void displayDecimalAnswer(int answer) {
        TextView decimalView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.decimal);
        decimalView.setText(String.valueOf(answer));
    }
}
```

EDITED: In addition to Saran's answer below would attempting to incorporate this[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435380/adding-multiple-values-to-a-textview-android) be a good path to follow?

Comment: Final answer can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38905750/converting-togglebutton-boolean-to-integer-values-then-add-together-in-a-textvie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end a combination of Saran's answer below, MRX's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38905750/converting-togglebutton-boolean-to-integer-values-then-add-together-in-a-textvie) and some lazy obstinacy from me got it to work.

```
@Override 
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
    if (compoundButton == toggle1) {
        if (isChecked) {
            toggle1Status = true;
        } else { 
            toggle1Status = false;
        } 
    } else if (compoundButton == toggle2) {
        if (isChecked) {
            toggle2Status = true;
        } else { 
            toggle2Status = false;
        } 
    } 
 displayDecimalAnswer();
} 

    /** 
     * Displays decimal answer. 
     */ 
    public void displayDecimalAnswer() {
       int valueOfOnes = (toggle1Status) ? 1 : 0;//Since toggle1Status is class level variable it will be accessibible
       int valueOfTwos = (toggle2Status) ? 2 : 0;
       int answer = valueOfOnes + valueOfTwos;

        TextView decimalView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.decimal);
        decimalView.setText(""+answer);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do ideally is you have to `setOnCheckedChangeListener` to both the toggles and then implement one `onCheckedChanged` method. Then you have to use `compoundButton` to check which view was toggled.

Your code should be something like this.

```
@Override
onCreate(){
    toggle1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggle1);
    toggle2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggle2);
    toggle1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    toggle2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
onCheckedChanged (CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked){
    if(compoundButton == toggle1){
        if(isChecked){
            //Your code if toggle 1 is checked
        } else {
            //Your code if toggle 1 is not checked
        }
    } else {
        if(compoundButton == toggle2){
            if(isChecked){
                //Your code if toggle 2 is checked
            } else {
                //Your code if toggle 2 is not checked
            }
       }
    }
}
```

And also in your code the declaration of the addValue method takes two variabales. i.e in line `public void addValues(int valueOfOnes, int valueOfTwos)` it is taking two variables which are `valueOfOnes` and `valueOfTwos`.

But when you are calling the method you are only passing one variable `addValues(valueOfTwos)`, that is the reason you are getting an error.

If in your declaration you are declared that the method will accept two variables of int, then in call to the method too you have to pass two variables of int.

Please correct that and it will solve your problem.

This is how you will save the value of your toggle.

```
boolean toggle1Status;
boolean toggle2Status;

@Override
onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
    if (compoundButton == toggle1) {

        if (isChecked) {
            //Toggle one was turned on.
            toggle1Status = true;

            if (toggle2Status) {
                //Your code if both the toggles are on
            } else {
                //Your code if toggle 1 is on and 2 is off
            }

        } else {
            //Toggle one was turned off.
            toggle1Status = false;

            if (toggle2Status) {
                //Your code if toggle 1 is off and toggle 2 is on.
            } else {
                //Your code if both the toggles are off.
            }

        }
    } else if (compoundButton == toggle2) {

        if (isChecked) {
            //Toggle two was turned on.
            toggle2Status = true;

            if (toggle1Status) {
                //Your code if both the toggles are on
            } else {
                //Your code if toggle 1 is off and 2 is on
            }

        } else {
            //Toggle two was turned off.
            toggle2Status = false;

            if (toggle1Status) {
                //Your code if toggle 1 is on and toggle 2 is off.
            } else {
                //Your code if both the toggles are off.
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Basically what we are doing here is we check first the state of toggle which was changed, then the check the state of the other toggle. And along with that, we are also saving the value of the current sate of toggle in a boolean variable for future use.

Comment: Thanks so much. Definitely a step closer!

 I added in 'public void' before onCheckedChanged, is that right?

Now '2' is displayed when I press toggle2 and 1 for toggle 1 but I still can't get the addValues method to accept two integers.

    `  public void addValues(int valueOfOnes, int valueOfTwos) {
        int totalValues;
        totalValues = valueOfOnes + valueOfTwos;
        displayDecimalAnswer(totalValues);
    }`

Gives errors 'addValues (int, int) in MainActivity cannot be applied to (int)

Comment: Thanks again. So now I have `addValues(valueOfOnes, valueOfTwos);` in both parts of the onCheckedChange method. Each button on it's own works fine but the `Binary equals: 0` textview does not add the two values together. It seems to only process the most recently pressed button and forget the value of the other.

So press toggle 1 it shows 01 = 1. Then press toggle2 and I get 11 = 2.

Press t1 again and 10 = 0 comes up.

I tried taking out the middle `else` but that makes no change to how it runs.

Comment: If you want to remember the toggle value, then use two variable to save the boolean value of each toggle. ie when the toggle one is on then the `booleanToggle1` should be set to true and this when toggle 2 is clicked you can use **`booleanToggle1` variabale to determine the state of toggle1**. And also don't forget to set the value of `booleanToggle1` back to false when the toggle1 is turned off. And the same you can do for the other toggle.

Comment: So including something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479058/how-to-make-a-boolean-variable-switch-between-true-and-false-every-time-a-method

Comment: that is too complected stuff. What I would suggest is simple branching of if else.

Comment: haha everything is complicated to me at the moment :)

What should I google to find out how to save a boolean value of each toggle?

Comment: Hey Saran, thank you. This looks like it will work but it also looks like it will be a nightmare when I add in 4 buttons or  8, 16 or 32..?
Maybe I'm too tired. Will have another look tomorrow. :) Thanks again.

Comment: That definitely works for 2 buttons, thanks. Am i right in thinking that I will need to double the amount of code for each successive button though?

Comment: Got there in the end :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38905750/converting-togglebutton-boolean-to-integer-values-then-add-together-in-a-textvie